# whether this php syntax is correct?

Tags: php, if-statement

hai guys,
   As i am a newbie i want to check a file path is an image or not

```
<? if(strpos($row['dfilepath'],'jpg') != false)
    {
      <img src=" <?= base_url().'/uploads/'.$row['dFilePath']?>" />
    } 
    else
    {
        <input type="button" onclick="loaddetails('<?php echo $row['dFilePath'];?>');" value="<?php echo $row['dFilePath'];?>">
    }
    ?>
```

whether my condition is correct or not..My error

> unexpected '<'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. This should work assuming that your `$row` array is valid.

```
<?php
    $ext = substr( $row[ 'dfilepath' ], strpos( $row[ 'dfilepath', '.' ) );
    if($ext == 'jpg')
    {
?>
      <img src="<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/'.$row['dFilePath']?>" />
<?php
    } 
    else
    {
?>
        <input type="button" onclick="loaddetails('<?php echo $row['dFilePath'];?>');" value="<?php echo $row['dFilePath'];?>">
<?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That will check if `$row['dfilepath']` contains the string 'jpg' anywhere within it, so it will not fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it so it only checks the last three chars of your file string, otherwise a file named "jpg.png" will currently cause your code to try to show the image:

```
<?php 
$file = $row['dfilepath'];
$file_ending = substr($file, strlen($file) - 3);
if('jpg' == $file_ending) { ?>
<img src=" <?php echo base_url().'/uploads/'.$file?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="button" onclick="loaddetails('<?php echo $file;?>');" value="<?php echo $file?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad habit to check file type using the extension. I can easily create a text file and rename it .jpg According to this code it would suddenly become an actual image. Or even more evil: I might exploit some bug in webbrowsers by creating a fake jpg that actually executes some code.

Besides that, I might name my jpeg files JPEG, jPG, jpG, JPeg or any other combination you might think of. Then there's also other formats than jpeg. I don't know the rest of your code, but maybe you want someone to allow uploading png or gif images.

If you want to be a little more sure that you actually have an image file, a more sure way to check is using [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize). That does require the GD extension though. If that function provides you with output that seems likely to be real you're a whole lot safer using that file as an image. Sure there are cases when you don't care and just want to check for the extension of a file. But I get a feeling this code is supposed to get a little public. A little example:

```
<?php
$file = $row['dfilepath'];
// where upload_dir is a function that somehow finds 
// the absolute path of the upload dir
$path = upload_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

$valid = array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png');

$info = getimagesize($path);
if($info !== false && in_array($info['mime'], $valid) {
    // more likely you'll actually have an image here
    // now you might want to print some html here, like:
    ?><img src="/uploads/<?php print $file; ?>" alt="" /><?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($row['dfilepath'],'jpg') != false)
```

This is a minor gotcha, if 'jpg' happens to occur at the start of the string being searched. strpos will properly return 0 for the hit, but 0 evaluates to false in a standard equality test. You'll end up with (false != false).

If you're using strpos to exclusively test for the existence of a substring, you have to use the strict === and !== operators (note the extra =), which not only compare values but types as well, where 0 !== false will evaluate to true. Integer 0 is not strictly equal to boolean false, even though they have the same value of 0.